# Angular strap typeahead Firefox issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pug, typeahead, angular-strap

Given this code :

```
input#client.form-control(bs-options="project.id as project.title for project in modalModel.projects"
    bs-typeahead
    name="project" ng-model="modalModel.task.mandate.id"
    placeholder="{{'common.selectOne' | translate}}")
```

In my model i will always get project.title instead of project.id

In Chrome it works ok. Do you have any idea how to fix it and get project.id in my model for Firefox?